# Changing model to use foreign key in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I'm currently trying to fix a small bug in an OS project.

Currently, when a tag is created it uses the Memory address of the User object:

tags_controller.rb

```
  def create
    ...
    new_tag = Tag.new(
      user: @current_user)
```

Which causes errors when trying to load tags from the database. I originally fixed it by storing the string of the username instead, but I'd like to set it up so that it uses a foreign key on `user_id`.

In the model for tags, I've added `belongs_to :user` but it complains about not having a user_id.

I'm assuming I need to generate a migration to remove the existing link to `user` and add `user_id`.

I'm pretty new to RoR and am not sure what the best way of getting rid of the old `user` and using `user_id` is. Do I need to modify the current code afterwards as well in the tags_controller or in the list?

Comment: For clarity, the memory address you're referring to appears as `<#User.....`

Answer (score 1):

First we want to create the new column:

`rails g migration AddUserToTags user:references`

This will create a file in `db/migrations`

```
class AddUserToTags < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     add_reference :tags, :user, index: true # creates a user_id column
  end
end
```

Then we run the migration with `rake db:migrate`. If we want to move the relationships which currently exist as usernames in the user column we could do something like this:

```
# comment out `belongs_to :user` in your tag model!
Tag.where.not(user: nil).find_each do |tag|
  tag.user_id = User.find_by!(username: tag.user).id
  tag.save!
end
```

We then want to remove the unorthodox user column to avoid confusion.

`rails g migration RemoveUserFromTags`.

Edit the migration to read like this:

```
class RemoveUserFromTags < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     remove_column :tags, :user
     remove_index :tags, :user if index_exists?(:tags, :user)
  end
end
```

And run it `rake db:migrate`

Comment: In Rails 5 you can run all the rake commands as `rails db:migrate` instead.

Comment: Thanks! Will `user` work in order to reference tags now, or do I have to use `user_id` in controllers?

Comment: Yes. I would recommen that you read the guides. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain how it works for you...

> Memory address of the User object

This is correct - you're basically telling Rails / Ruby to save the *Object*, which it obviously cannot due to *only* having the `user` attribute to save it to.

Your problem is that you're trying to save your *entire* object in that field. If you used the following, it would work as you want:

```
new_tag = Tag.new(
      user: @current_user.id)
```

You could then get it working by assigning the `foreign_key` to `user`:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :tags, foreign_key: "user"
end
```

This would allow you to call the following:

```
@tag = current_user.tags.new tag_params
```

--

Since you want to learn how to do it, here's how you *should* go about it:

```
#app/models/tag.rb
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :tags
end
```

Here is a description of this [association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association):

[image]

> I need to generate a migration to remove the existing link to user

You are correct, but don't fool yourself. The "link" you speak of is just the title of a column... nothing more. If your `user` column exists already, you can just change it to `user_id` (or reference the foreign key as "user" as above):

```
$ rails g migration ChangeUserForeignKey

#db/migrate/change_user_foreign_key.... .rb
class ChangeUserForeignKey < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      rename_column :tags, :user, :user_id
   end
end

$ rake db:migrate
```

Comment: The asker used usernames (strings) instead of ids in the user column. Which is why you cannot simply rename the column. He could change the type of the column in a migration but you would still have to do the steps of looking up each user by username and replacing the string with an ID - before typecasting.